# How to manage 1 Billion+ rows in sqlite database for Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating my first Android app, a random number generator.  For my design, **I need to create a sqlite table that has 1,348,621,560** rows with around **16 columns each**.  I need all rows available at all times, but without relational data.  The table will not grow, and I will only run simple queries that scan the table and return a few records.

*My question:*
Is this even possible? I've looked into partitioning tables, sharding, keeping the table in one piece, etc..  If this is possible, what is the best way to maintain efficiency and reliability?

**UPDATE:**
Lots of responders have informed me that this approach is not the most elegant nor the most efficient.  However, I have found information that **PostgresQL can easily handle the amount of data I will create.**  Thanks to everyone who responded!

Comment: For a random number generator?  You're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Just in case you haven't done the math-  even at 1 integer per column with no metadata on the table, thats 64GB for the table.  I can't think of an Android device that would even fit on

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I had no idea how to compute the size of this monster.  Thanks.

Comment: If this doesn't work on Android, I'd like to keep work on it and develop an app that acceses a server with the data.

Comment: @Mickydidymus Take a look at https://www.random.org/randomness/ If you need that large of a table, then you are likely doing something wrong. That article contains a good deal of information on RNGs and how they work.

Comment: Good article, thanks!

Comment: Any info on my question?  If I did need this size database how would I implement it in sqlite?  Android or otherwise?

Comment: @Mickydidymus to the question: you wouldn't do it at all, as it is quite certainly wrong. Consider to re-word your question including what you want to do (the rationale for the table), and it is quite likely someone can explain to you why it is wrong and what to do instead (if your question becomes off-topic here with that change: there are other Stack exchange sites specializing on CS Theory or Cryptography).

Comment: @Mickydidymus " I need all rows available at all times, but without relational data" this phrase means you need a random generator to fill your table, why not using that random generator to get your randoms just in time?

Comment: True, I'm looking to store and statistically evaluate a large sample of data.  So, the database is more for having a read-only set of numbers that are categeorized by different characteristics.